# OAuthException: Unsafe?

Tags: javascript, oauth, facebook-opengraph

I've a error message like this:

> Error occured Type: OAuthException Message: Sorry, this post contains
>   a blocked URL: The content you're trying to share includes a link
>   that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe:
>
> Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Sorry, this post contains
>   a blocked URL
>
> For more information, visit the Help Center. If you think you're
>   seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

When I try to post an action. On this link, nothing is unsafe for me... I don't understand why this url is blocked ?!

The url: http://zoucky.com/trop-mignon-le-bebe-qui-fait-de-la-muscu-non/

Any idea ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? ive recently gotten the same thing for a clients site.